# What tool to use for searching by date and ranking in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net

I was wondering what could be the best solution for the following requirement:

On a CMS Web site, I need to research, based on Free text keyword, articles created in Sitecore. Those articles are Sitecore Items created in a specific folder structure.

- Content
  ----- Newsletter
  --------V 1
  --------V 2

Is Lucene the best option to retrieve any article based on the Free Text?
The articles have to be appear on the screen based on two options: By Date or by ranking (Number of time the Free text keyword appear in the article) 
Is there any other options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lucene is definitely your best option, since it is already used by Sitecore and makes integration much easier.

There is a very good article and walk-through on Lucene:

- [Lucene Query walk-through](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/06/LuceneQuery1.aspx)

But it would be better to use the Advanced Database Crawler:

- [Get latest news using Sitecore AdvancedDatabaseCrawler Lucene index](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/get-latest-news-using-sitecore-advanceddatabasecrawler-lucene-index/)
- [Using Advanced Database Crawler](http://sitecoredevs.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/using-advanced-database-crawler/)
- [Advanced Database Crawler and Dynamic Fields](http://www.letsdositecore.com/advanced-database-crawler-and-dynamic-fields/)

Comment: I believe after SC 6.5 Lucene is no longer supported. I researched when I was searching for the same stuff. But at last I used Advanced DB Crawler.

Comment: What tells you that Lucene support will be dropped? It's not true! I agree with Jammykam; use the Advanced Database Crawler to index and search through your content.

Comment: I agree with Ruud. Sitecore uses Lucene internally and 6.6 supports Lucene, in fact they are using a newer version 2.9.4.1. Item Buckets also utilizes Lucene, which is one of the main offerings in Sitecore 7